# Laravel Eloquent for count not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-9

In my Laravel application, I'm trying to display a count with a chart on my view where my employee status is a subcontractor.

In my user's table, I have a column called is_subcontractor, and if the user is a subcontractor, it will store as 1, and if not, 0.

This is the MySQL query I'm currently running,

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT (users.id)) FROM users
INNER JOIN project_track_records ON users.id=project_track_records.user_id
INNER JOIN projects ON projects.id=project_track_records.project_id 
WHERE users.is_subcontractor=1 AND projects.company_id=583;
```

This output's me "6."

And this is the laravel eloquent I'm running for the above query.

```
$subcontractorsCount = User::join('project_track_records', 'users.id', '=', 'project_track_records.user_id')
            ->join('projects', 'projects.id', '=', 'project_track_records.project_id')
            ->when($request->filled('project_ids'), function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->whereIn('project_track_records.project_id', $request->get('project_ids'));
                })
            ->where('users.is_subcontractor', 1)
            ->where('projects.company_id', $company->id)
            ->when($request->filled('project_ids'), function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('projects.id', $request->get('project_ids'));
                })
            ->distinct()   
            ->count('users.id');
```

And in my view (a vue component), I have a filter to filter this chart by the projects, it's a dropdown with a set of projects, and the user can select one or more projects at a time. Once the user selects the projects he needs, it'll load the project IDs to the payload and filter the chart and the count accordingly.

But when I select all the projects and then try to filter it instead of giving 6, it only gives me 2. So, where do I need to fix my eloquent to filter the results correctly?

Comment: A useful way to debug these situation is to use `->toSql()` instead of the `->get()` or in this case `->count()`. Similarly you can use `->getBindings()` to get the data it adds to the data placeholders. That will tell you how your generated query is different from your expected query. I would expect the extra query in the `->when(...)` to be `->whereIn(...)` instead of `->where(...)`.

Comment: Also note that that condition is not in the original query at all, so I can't tell you if that filters out some of the users.